# You must have 5 reputation to participate on which site again?

Tags: bug, status-completed, sffaq

The [meta.SF FAQ](https://meta.serverfault.com/faq) states, in part:

> You must have at least 5 reputation on the main website to participate on Server Fault.

Should it not say that you must have 5 reputation *on Server Fault* to participate *on Meta*?

Comment: +1 - might leave this one for the devs, they do keep an eye on the metas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording will be corrected with our next build, thanks for pointing it out.

You are correct that you need 5 reputation on the main site in order to participate on the child meta.